# Docker Hostname inside container

Tags: docker

I'm using a docker container to run some browser tests.

For some OAuth workflow, I need a custom hostname that I can forward to the OAuth site, for example `my.dev.site`.

Usually in non-docker environments, I just add an entry to the `/etc/hosts` file that casts `my.dev.site` to `127.0.0.1`

Is this possible with docker and if so, how?

Comment: Just add an entry to your `/etc/hosts` file inside your container?

Comment: That just might be the simplest answer ever, i wasn't aware that there's a `/etc/hosts` file in containers (for example for the `ubuntu` base image). I'll have to try first. Thanks @super

Answer (score 1):

By default, docker container hosts are identified by their name.

However, in a compose file, you could use `extra_host` field to add hostnames to /etc/hosts within containers.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#extra_hosts

```yaml
extra_hosts:
  - "my.dev.site:127.0.0.1"
```

And the docker run version

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings

`docker run --add-host my.dev.site:127.0.0.1 <image>`